# Reversing substrings in parentheses

Tags: python, strings, python-2.x

Problem:
The task is to reverse the strings contained in each pair of matching parentheses, starting from the innermost pair. The results string should not contain any parentheses.

Example:

```
>>> s = "a(bc)de"
>>> reverseParentheses(s)
"acbde"
>>> s = "The ((quick (brown) (fox) jumps over the lazy) dog)"
>>> reverseParentheses(s)
"The god quick nworb xof jumps over the lazy"
```

To achieve this task I have written the following piece of code:

```
def reverseParentheses(s):
 i = 0
 brackarray = []
 recursivearray = []
 a = []
 numberofbrack = -1
 alteredstring = s


 chars = "()"
 for char in chars:
  alteredstring = alteredstring.replace(char, "")

 while i < len(s):

  if s[i] == '(':
   j = i
   numberofbrack = numberofbrack + 1
   j = j - numberofbrack
   brackarray.append(j)


  if s[i] == ')':
   m = i
   numberofbrack = numberofbrack + 1
   m = m- numberofbrack
   n = brackarray.pop()
   recursivearray.append((n,m))


  i = i+1

 for item in recursivearray:
  lenas = len(alteredstring)
  z = recursive(item[0], item[1], alteredstring)
  alteredstring1 =  alteredstring[0:item[0]]
  alteredstring2 = alteredstring[item[1]:lenas]
  alteredstring =  alteredstring1+z+alteredstring2


 return alteredstring


def recursive(start, end, string):
  y = string[start:end]
  string = y[::-1]
  return string
```

Could somebody please review above code and provide suggestions and improvements?

Comment: @Coal_ The example looks correct to me. Since `quick` is inside two levels of parentheses, it gets reversed twice, and thus should still appear as `quick`.

Answer (score 6):

Please follow the official [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide.  In particular, **indentation** matters a lot in Python!  One space per level of indentation is *much* too stingy for readability; four spaces is standard.  Also, using `lowercase_with_underscores` for function and variable names is the norm.

For this kind of function, I would strongly recommend writing a **docstring with [doctests](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html)**.  You could easily test your code by running `python -mdoctest reverse.py`.

`recursive` is a poorly named function: it's not recursive, and the name tells you nothing about what it does.  I'd call it `extract_and_reverse_substring`.

You have **too many variables**, which makes the code confusing.  In particular, `a` is never used!  Furthermore, a lot of the complication arises from **your decision to strip out all of the parentheses at the beginning**, to form `alteredstring`.  If you *keep* the parentheses, and strip them out *afterwards*, then you wouldn't need `alteredstring`, `numberofbrack`, and `recursivearray`, because that information would still be preserved in the string itself.

Python strings are immutable.  When doing many repositioning operations on the characters in a string, consider using a list instead, for efficiency.  That would allow you to replace individual characters without allocating new strings.

### Suggested solution

```
def reverse_parentheses(s):
    """
    Reverse the strings contained in each pair of matching parentheses,
    starting from the innermost pair. The results string should not contain
    any parentheses.

    >>> reverse_parentheses('a(bc)de')
    'acbde'

    >>> reverse_parentheses(
    ...     'The ((quick (brown) (fox) jumps over the lazy) dog)'
    ... )
    'The god quick nworb xof jumps over the lazy'
    """
    chars = list(s)
    open_bracket_indexes = []
    for i, c in enumerate(chars):
        if c == '(':
            open_bracket_indexes.append(i)
        elif c == ')':
            j = open_bracket_indexes.pop()
            chars[j:i] = chars[i:j:-1]
    if open_bracket_indexes:
        raise ArgumentError('Unclosed parenthesis')
    return ''.join(c for c in chars if c not in '()')
```

Answer (score 2):

A sidenote on style. Function names in Python should be lower case and separated with underscores instead of camelCase e.g. `function_name`

Also, I recommend you switch out that `while i < len(s):` with

```
for i in "string":
    #do something with i'th character
```

It removes the need to track a counter, and looks cleaner and more functional.

I also recommend you have a "Stack" helper class. It will really help clean up this implementation since you can just push on the stack and take it out when needed. Automatic reversal!

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18279878/138228

Comment: In `for i in "string"`, `i` itself is one character of the string, it is not an index ("i'th character"). As such it would be better to name it `c` or `ch`, not `i`.